# Content goes out of a background

Tags: css, html

I have a section which contain a content and I have added a background to it , I want content to be inside the background, unfortunately am not be able to get what I want.

Here is visual of what is expected[image]

Here is what I have done so far : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/8w36hrdk/

Here is HTML

```
<div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ">
            <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_header">
                <h5>Faq</h5>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vidit mundi gubergren ne usu, porro evertitur vix et.
.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie">
                <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card card-0 card">

                    <a class="pytania" data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block0" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block0">
                        Demo1
                    </a>
                    <div id="test-block0" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            Po kliknięciu w pytanie rozwija się dropdown z odpowiedzią na pytanie, jak klikniemy na
                            inne to się zwija. Najlepiej, żeby były to max. 2 zdania.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card card-0 card">
                    <a class="pytania" data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block2">
                         Demo1
                    </a>
                    <div id="test-block1" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            Po kliknięciu w pytanie rozwija się dropdown z odpowiedzią na pytanie, jak klikniemy na
                            inne to się zwija. Najlepiej, żeby były to max. 2 zdania.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card card-0 card">
                    <a class="pytania" data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
                       Demo1
                    </a>
                    <div id="test-block2" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            Po kliknięciu w pytanie rozwija się dropdown z odpowiedzią na pytanie, jak klikniemy na
                            inne to się zwija. Najlepiej, żeby były to max. 2 zdania.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card card-0 card">
                    <a class="pytania" data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
                      Demo1
                    </a>
                    <div id="test-block3" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            Po kliknięciu w pytanie rozwija się dropdown z odpowiedzią na pytanie, jak klikniemy na
                            inne to się zwija. Najlepiej, żeby były to max. 2 zdania.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card card-0 card">
                    <a class="pytania" data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block4" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
                        Demo1
                    </a>
                    <div id="test-block4" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            Po kliknięciu w pytanie rozwija się dropdown z odpowiedzią na pytanie, jak klikniemy na
                            inne to się zwija. Najlepiej, żeby były to max. 2 zdania.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card card-0 card">
                    <a class="pytania" data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block5" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
                       Demo1
                    </a>
                    <div id="test-block5" class="collapse">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            Po kliknięciu w pytanie rozwija się dropdown z odpowiedzią na pytanie, jak klikniemy na
                            inne to się zwija. Najlepiej, żeby były to max. 2 zdania.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is css

```
.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ {
    /* margin-top: 80px; */
    padding: 231px 0px;
    background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/8K7.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 150vw;
    background-position: right 0;
}
.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie-card {
    width: 536px;
    height: 132px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 41px;
}
.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_pytanie {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_header p {
    width: 451px;
    height: 184px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    color: #707070;
}
.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ_header {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

I tried different combination but I could not manage to solve the problem,

what do I need to do to get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I normally use percents or ems rather than pixels, makes life easier

Also try adding the below in your css file

```
body, html {
height:100%;
width : 100%;
max-height:100%;
max-width : 100%;
}
```

Comment: hii Manuraj please this is not problem of autoflow or whatsoever your trying to do , its about a section which have a background and I want the contet to fit inside the image , as Imahe shows above (expected resuslt)

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to give the following div a width.  For example:

```
.marketing-main-page-content-FAQ {
    /* margin-top: 80px; */
    padding: 231px 0px;
    background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/8K7.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 150vw;
    background-position: right 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 500px;  //set a width here
}
```

This will keep all your content within and not shift outside the box.

Have updated the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8w36hrdk/13/

Comment: does it work in your fiddle according to expected result?